# How to use a smaller font in lightning-datatable?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, css, lightning-datatable

We are in the process of moving from Classic to Lightning. I am rebuilding some Visualforce pages to Lightning Web Components. One of the many challenges is this one:

The font that is used in a lightning-datatable is much larger than that in a Visualforce apex:pageBlockTable. This causes data to be illegible (not enough data is visible anymore).

I guess this has to be solved with CSS class or style. I am a CSS newbie and, also, googling on lightning-datatable gives me lots of aura answers that do not seem to work for LWC. How can I change the font sizes of all data in a lightning-datatable to - say - 80%?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't *specifically* target the font inside, but you can shrink the entire table via `zoom`:

```
.eighty-percent {
    zoom: 80%;
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable class="eighty-percent" data={data} columns={cols} key-field="id">
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track data = [{id:'1',name:'Demo'}];
    @track cols = [{label:'Name',fieldName:'name'}];
}
```

---

I created a [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/1lWeUnx2/1/edit) that demonstrates this.

Comment: @sfdxfox will this be blocked by locker service or is it wrong https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/EWbh5yas/1/edit

Comment: @User6670 Locker Service doesn't affect CSS. The Shadow DOM does. Looking at the table, it appears that slds-table is set to a font-size of "inherit", so changing it from a parent container (as in your example) is also supported. If the font-size was embedded in the table, this trick would not work. It should be safe to use either method.

Comment: It's just as easy as it looks. The table itself still spans the entire width of the window, but the used fonts are all decreased in size. Thanks!

Comment: Can I use this `zoom`attribute for CustomDataTable as well?

Comment: @IsuruBuddhikaHerath Yes, it should work just fine for a custom data table.

Comment: @sfdcfox previously it was not worked. Then it was wrapped into a `div` and style was set to `div`. Now I tried again after your comment. Ha haa. It is working!!!
May be I have done some mistake or not deployed properly in previous instance. Thanks!